# Benchmarks to compare two azure data factory pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have built two pipelines with different transformations for the same functionality.

Are there any benchmarks to compare these two pipelines in terms of efficiency and/or resource utilization?

To explain in detail:
Pipeline 1 : Uses only 2 Mapping data flows. One with 4 transformations and other with 20 transformations.
Pipeline 2 : Uses 2 Mapping data flows. One with 4 transformations , second DF other with 15 transformations and with Databricks notebook.

I want to compare these two pipelines in terms of
1.Efficieny
2.Resource utilization
3.Costs

Any inputs?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think you could compare the outputs of the pipelines, the output contains the value what you want.

Here's the output example of pipeline executing:

```
{
    "dataRead": 8192,
    "dataWritten": 612,
    "filesRead": 1,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 2,
    "rowsRead": 1,
    "rowsCopied": 1,
    "copyDuration": 12,
    "throughput": 0.667,
    "errors": [],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US)",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.06666666666666667,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
                "region": "Central US"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                "region": "East US"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "2020-09-01T08:20:09.1734161Z",
            "duration": 12,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 9
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 3,
                    "details": {
                        "listingSource": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        },
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 9,
                "transferDuration": 3
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

On Portal:

[image]

[image]